# How to query all the fileds from a mongodb document using Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I am trying to query a mongodb document using .NET Driver, i want to fetch all the fields in a particular document WITHOUT creating a class object because these documents are generated dynamically and i know only one field name ie., _id how can i fetch the entire document

```
public class usermodal
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

}
protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // //BsonDocument modal = new BsonDocument;
    string id = "e0b4a7b7-096a-4a8a-b942-83fccf81e6c5";
    var client = new MongoClient(mongocon);
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Mydb");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<usermodal>("new");
    var filter = Builders<usermodal>.Filter.Eq("_id", id); //filter the bson document based on ID

    // var list = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
    //var filterx = new BsonDocument("_id", "e0b4a7b7-096a-4a8a-b942-83fccf81e6c5");

    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();


    GridView1.DataSource = result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

this works fine when the fields are know

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected  void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // //BsonDocument modal = new BsonDocument;
    string id = "e0b4a7b7-096a-4a8a-b942-83fccf81e6c5";
    var client = new MongoClient(mongocon);
    var db = client.GetDatabase("Mydb");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<dynamic>("new");
    var filter = Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Eq("_id", id); //filter the bson document based on ID

    // var list = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
    //var filterx = new BsonDocument("_id", "e0b4a7b7-096a-4a8a-b942-83fccf81e6c5");

    var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();


    GridView1.DataSource = result;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: appreciate your answer but i am getting this error as **The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content**

Comment: can you please show what response is coming from db

Comment: I get this response when i removed gridview and list from the code above and create a response ...... **find({ "_id" : "e0b4a7b7-096a-4a8a-b942-83fccf81e6c5" })**